# what do two square brackets next to eachother do in C

Tags: python, c

what do two square brackets next to eachother do in C, Is it the same as it is in python?

In python it would be

```
lst = [1,2,3,[1,2,3]]
lst[3][1]
```

and the second line would give `2`.

In C does it function the same?

Comment: In C you don't have "lists" in the way that Python does, you have *arrays*. And arrays are a homogeneous container, all elements must be of the same type. Lists in Python are heterogeneous, and can contain a mix of elements and element types. Not to mention that the syntax for initializing Python lists and C arrays are very different. Lastly, C arrays (as a whole) can't be assigned to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In python it would be lst = [1,2,3,[1,2,3]] lst[3][1] and that would be 2 in the second list. In C does it function the same?

Yes and no. Well more like no and yes really:

- C array literal are nothing like Python's, and they are not bracketed, and they're statically typed
- assuming `lst` is an array of arrays, `lst[3][1]` will indeed return the second element of the 4th, however
- the semantics of indexing in C are very different (and a lot more error prone) than Python's
- in fact the semantics of C arrays in general are very, very different from the semantics of Python's list, and assuming they work similarly is outright dangerous

If you have to work with C, you really should *learn C* not just try to muddle through by semi-random equivalence. C is not a big language, but it's neither easy nor forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

In C you can create arrays. 1D or multidimensional arrays...
have a look at [c-multi-dimensional-arrays](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: You can do the exact same in python, and that's not an actual multidimensional array, it's just nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support lists in the same way as python. The type that might be considered similar to a python list might be an array of `union`. But it is up to the C programmer to implement it.

In C, the expression *E<sub>1</sub>*`[`*E<sub>2</sub>*`]` is equivalent to `*(`*E<sub>1</sub>*`+`*E<sub>2</sub>*`)`. This means that the expression *E<sub>1</sub>*`+`*E<sub>2</sub>* must result in a valid pointer value that can be dereferenced.

Idiomatically, *E<sub>1</sub>* would take on the value of the address of the first element of an array, and *E<sub>2</sub>* would be an index into the array. In most expressions, an array object will take on the value of the address of its first element.

C does not support lists in the same way as python. A C data structure type that might be considered similar to a python list could be an array of `struct`, where the `struct` contains a `union` to represent the various different types of values that could be stored. This is required, since arrays in C are defined to be a contiguous collection of elements of the same type. So, it is up to the C programmer to implement it a type that can store a variety of types, and this is achieved with a `union`.

Just throwing together something really simple, but ugly:

```
#define MKLIST(...) { __VA_ARGS__, { LET_None } }
#define MKLIST_int(X) { LET_int, { .v_int = (X) } }
//...
#define MKLIST_List(X) { LET_List, { .v_list = (X) } }

enum ListElementType {
    LET_None,
    LET_int,
    //...
    LET_List,
};

struct ListElement {
    enum ListElementType type;
    union {
        int v_int;
        //...
        struct ListElement *v_list;
    } value;
};
```

And then,

```
struct ListElement sublist[] =
    MKLIST(MKLIST_int(1), MKLIST_int(2), MKLIST_int(3));
struct ListElement list[] =
    MKLIST(MKLIST_int(1), MKLIST_int(2), MKLIST_int(3),
         MKLIST_List(sublist));
```

And while you can see you could use this to store a variety of values, you can not retrieve them as naturally as in python, since you have to test if the element is the type you are expecting to retrieve.

```
int
List_getint (struct ListElement *x, int i) {
    assert(x[i].type == LET_int);
    return x[i].value.v_int;
}

struct ListElement *
List_getlist (struct ListElement *x, int i) {
    assert(x[i].type == LET_List);
    return x[i].value.v_list;
}
```

And then,

```
printf("%d\n", List_getint(List_getlist(list, 3), 1));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVNfa8IwEH/PpziUQSpdxe3RdeCDjDG3hylDcBJcG12gRmlTcUg/e5dL05pJ2cuWh5K73O/PXdLoehNFZdkVMkrymMNdpmKxCz7vyTm1yjKeKsyRbszXQnJ4fpo8Tmc0CAIPTsDY24iNXh@mjPk6nIxn7GWnqwooLhBMSEXnni3SAdYHB9xBCHiCmH5fE18iJyJzoBhZbKK3DphwmW8Bz8cJ33KpZl97DicCetXO/CZCCyaoNOu0oSfFkJBMpXmkXD7L1Sqj9GdojnMpdtKW4sIOTZ/DJnWWxNUi1KuaqxAFHFZJrtnRleYhWMk2XCEzbUMffaMqPGujukd6XIhlgEYhDOsZeJVGylWeSjAVRi2wlovWQfQaD@YO/mQCQb@4qOZQmM5huxISaM3YoprlHwhYLCFs5mufrPMOB57vPsubn@GtZ@208P8Dud9gHYLqkVv3qG@K9qmGrGnnKn6XHR@ce6fu/Gli/glNDQPEFmX5DQ)

Comment: In C++, it is much easier and more natural to support a notion of a python like list, using `std::any`.